# whitespace in path in bash command python file

Tags: python, bash, pip

I set up a python virtual environment in python 3.6. the venv works, but pip does not. When running a pip command I get this error:

```
-bash: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/McNeel/Rhinoceros/Scripts/craftr_rhino/venv/bin/pip: "/Users/username/Library/Application\: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

There seems to be a problem with the white space in the bash command in the (by virtualenv generated) pip file:

```
#!"/Users/username/Library/Application Support/McNeel/Rhinoceros/Scripts/craftr_rhino/venv/bin/python3"

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

The path is already in between quotations, how can I get pip to understand the bash command?

**edit:**

Already tried:

```
".../Application\ Support/..."
".../Application\\ Support/..."
'.../Application Support/...'
```

Comment: have you tried: `#!/Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/McNeel/Rhinoceros/Scripts/craftr_rhino/venv/bin/python3` ?

Comment: note: this is a very bad idea to hardcode python, and added in a path with bloody spaces. That's looking for trouble.

Comment: have you tried without the quotes as well?

Comment: have you tried to rename Application Support into Application_Support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No quotation needed for bash and backslash all white spaces like this:

```
#!/Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/McNeel/Rhinoceros/Scripts/craftr_rhino/venv/bin/python3
```

I'm not on a Mac now, but I believe there is somewhere on OSX a command call env, on linux is under /usr/bin path, that can brings up your python environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And you just have to set the python3.6 in our $python shell var when call your script or set it to your bash.rc file

Comment: This helped! The first did not work, but referencing the env command did.